# Conexão Webservice SOAP HTTPS PHP ( Santander )

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estou tentando realizar a conexão com um webservice SOAP usando um client php.

O client eu monto assim:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://urlwebservice?wsdl);
```

Quando eu chamo a função:

```
$client->__getFunctions();
```

Recebo o seguinte retorno:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'urlwebservice?wsdl' : failed to load external entity 'urlwebservice'
```

Quando acesso a url no navegador, recebo um 403-Forbidden, mas se tenho um certificado A1 instalado na máquina ele pergunta se eu quero utilizar o mesmo e então abre o webservice com o seu xml wsdl.

Esse erro pode ter haver com o envio o certificado? Ou é outro erro? Para enviar o certificado fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$params = array(
    'local_cert' => 'path/to/cert.cer',
    'passphrase' => 'chave' //já passei com e sem a chave
);
$client = new SoapClient('https://urlwebservice?wsdl', $params);
```

Já passei outros parâmetros que pesquisei pela internet, mas em todos os casos o erro continua o mesmo!

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é um erro do servidor no qual você está tentando se conectar, alguma autorização, token ou hash de segurança, pode estar especificado no manual, parâmetros  como

```
'soapopations' => array(
                'exceptions'         => true ,
                'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_1 ,
                'features'           => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS ,
                'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE ,
                'connection_timeout' => 500 ,
                'trace'              => true ,
            ),
```

já tentou?

Comment: Olá @FelipeDuarte, depois de uma árdua jornada conseguir realizar a integração com o Banco, e realmente nesse caso há a necessidade do cadastro do certificado no banco (Santander nesse caso). Porém além desse problema tivemos problemas com o firewall da checkpoint, pois conseguimos integrar e depois parou, pois o firewall estava bloqueando o acesso utilizando o certificado da máquina, foi necessário cadastrar o certificado no firewall para que a conexão se mantivesse permanentemente. Obrigado.

Comment: @wmengue, haha que bom, infelizmente muita coisa passa despercebido nessas integrações, a propósito editei a pergunta especificando uma integração com o 'santander', para que a mesma possa ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema futuramente :)